# socket.io works on localhost AND local network but not when deployed on a server

Tags: javascript, python, socket.io, python-socketio

I am building a socket.io app with the python implementation on the server side and the JS client.

When I test my app on my machine everything works, I can connect with multiple clients and exchange data with the server.
The app also works, when I access it from other machines in my local network, I host the app on my desktop and access it from my laptop and smartphone.

When I host the app on one of my servers (VPS at Hetzner), it does not work properly. I can still access the app and load the html/js client. The client also starts a socket.io connection with the server, I can see the `connect` event on the server.
But then nothing more works. I cannot emit events and I don't receive data from the server.

When I look into the network tab in my browser, I can see several GET requests (HTML, JS, CSS,...) and then periodic GET requests to `<myserver>/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=NVPxxx`.
Each of these GET requests triggers the `connect` event on the server, I guess that the connection never really happens completely.

My server code looks like this:

```py
import socketio
import eventlet
import pandas as pd

sio = socketio.Server()
app = socketio.WSGIApp(sio, static_files={ # The client is served here
   '/': './public/'
})

@sio.event
def connect(sid, environ):
   print("Connection from: " + sid)
   pushstate(sid)

<... more vent handlers etc. ...>

def run():
   eventlet.wsgi.server(eventlet.listen(('localhost', 5000)), app)

if __name__ == '__main__':
   run()
```

The server runs behind a nginx reverse proxy that handles SSL and is (to my knowledge) correctly configured to proxy websocket connections.
To make sure my proxy config is not the source of the problem, I also ran the server directly. Even without the reverse proxy I have the same problems.

The client looks like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport">
  <title>MyApp</title>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BmbxuPwQa2lc/FVzBcNJ7UAyJxM6wuqIj61tLrc4wSX0szH/Ev+nYRRuWlolflfl" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    More HTML here
  </div>

  <script src="https://cdn.socket.io/3.1.1/socket.io.min.js" integrity="sha384-gDaozqUvc4HTgo8iZjwth73C6dDDeOJsAgpxBcMpZYztUfjHXpzrpdrHRdVp8ySO" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-b5kHyXgcpbZJO/tY9Ul7kGkf1S0CWuKcCD38l8YkeH8z8QjE0GmW1gYU5S9FOnJ0" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="index.js"></script> <!-- Here is the interesting part-->
</body>

</html>
```

And the JS part in index.js:

```js
const sio = io() // Socket.IO conenction

sio.on('update', (data) => {
    console.log(data)
    update_Data(data) // do all Data updates
});

// example onClick there are more in the actual Code
$("#delete").click(function () {
    sio.emit('remove', {name: $("input#Name").val()}, (result) => {
        if (!result){
            alert("Could not delete!");
        }
    });
});
```

Edit ---
Here are the logs from the server.
I connected a single client, while running the server without reverse proxy.
When a client connects, the server sends them an update event. In this test the Server had no data yet, so the data in update is empty.

```
Server initialized for eventlet.
(6129) wsgi starting up on http://0.0.0.0:80
(6129) accepted ('77.21.X.X', 2540)
3c59561367e34bbcbd09361879428671: Sending packet OPEN data {'sid': '3c59561367e34bbcbd09361879428671', 'upgrades': ['websocket'], 'pingTimeout': 60000, 'pingInterval': 25000}
emitting event "update" to 3c59561367e34bbcbd09361879428671 [/]
3c59561367e34bbcbd09361879428671: Sending packet MESSAGE data 2["update",[]]
3c59561367e34bbcbd09361879428671: Sending packet MESSAGE data 0
77.21.X.X - - [26/Feb/2021 16:00:05] "GET /socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=NVV4Op5 HTTP/1.1" 200 390 0.004566
f4934759613140be898f2d999767c728: Sending packet OPEN data {'sid': 'f4934759613140be898f2d999767c728', 'upgrades': ['websocket'], 'pingTimeout': 60000, 'pingInterval': 25000}
emitting event "update" to f4934759613140be898f2d999767c728 [/]
f4934759613140be898f2d999767c728: Sending packet MESSAGE data 2["update",[]]
f4934759613140be898f2d999767c728: Sending packet MESSAGE data 0
77.21.X.X - - [26/Feb/2021 16:00:10] "GET /socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=NVV4Q2F HTTP/1.1" 200 390 0.005562
34343bbd72e24136a71f94b276e659ad: Sending packet OPEN data {'sid': '34343bbd72e24136a71f94b276e659ad', 'upgrades': ['websocket'], 'pingTimeout': 60000, 'pingInterval': 25000}
emitting event "update" to 34343bbd72e24136a71f94b276e659ad [/]
34343bbd72e24136a71f94b276e659ad: Sending packet MESSAGE data 2["update",[]]
34343bbd72e24136a71f94b276e659ad: Sending packet MESSAGE data 0
77.21.X.X - - [26/Feb/2021 16:00:15] "GET /socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=NVV4RGt HTTP/1.1" 200 390 0.005401
^Cwsgi exiting
(6129) wsgi exited, is_accepting=True
```

The client does not seem to produce any debug output on the console, even with `localStorage.debug = '*';` and the debug enabled socket.io client.
Here is a screenshot of the network tab in chrome.
[image: Network Tab chrome]

The logs were taken after each other, hence the IDs do not match.

Comment: You need to add logs for your server and client to your question, without the logs it is pretty much a guessing game. See the troublshooting section of the Flask-SocketIO docs if you don't know how to enable logs.

Comment: @Miguel I added the logs from the server, but my client did not produce any logs, so I added a screenshot of the networks tab, I hope this helps

Comment: In the same way as the server, the client needs to have logging enabled to produce any logs. As a side question, are you sure you are using versions of client and server that are compatible with each other? Check out the version compatibility table in the Flask-SocketIO documentation.

Comment: @Miguel You found my problem... my server version was too old... and my local dev environment had a newer version, that's why it worked in my local network but not on the server.